# No sound at all on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound

Sound isn't working at all, except when I connect my headset. I think it's hardware problem? What can I do to fix it? I have a ThinkPad with HDA Intel PCH. I even tried filling a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1096574) report, but now I think I shouldn't have as it majorly seems to be a hardware support problem. Also, a guy posted something on the bug report that I can't make sense of (Feeling so ~n00b right now [._.] ). I think I am supposed to patch something, not really sure :(

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like hardware problem. have you tried loading sound drivers once again or updating sound drivers?

Comment: @VRU umm, I did. Did you try reading the bug report I linked? If not, do you know how to install patch on linux? A guy on launchpad linked me to a patch for ThinkPad's. It's here: http://goo.gl/lDYYb

Comment: yeah, I have gone through it and you said you could not try it either 12.04 version as it used to crash regularly. Have you ever checked the sound on your laptop?

Comment: Yeah, it's a dual boot (Windows 8). It works fine on Windows 8.

Comment: Nope... sorry, I didn't knew about any such link but I'll try it now. And I really appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: Find the link here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting